# How to keep track of user once he/she logs in (Flask)

Tags: javascript, python, html, authentication, flask

I created two simple views on my website. In the first one the user logs in and I set the session to 'logged_in':

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  error = None
  if request.method == 'POST':
    result = query_db('select * from user where (user_name = ? and password = ?)',
            [request.form['username'], request.form['password']], one=True)
  if result is None:
        error = 'Invalid username and/or password'
    else:
        id, username, password = result
        session['logged_in'] = True
        return redirect(url_for('add_form'))
return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

In another one I have a form that my user can fill in. I pass the data retrieved from the form to my backend and I'd like to store it in a database with the username (or id) as the primary key. I'm not sure what's the best way of keeping track of my username/userid? At this point I just know that the user is logged in. I could store the username as a global variable or maybe pass it as an argument to one of my functions, but these seem like bad solutions to me. Is there any better way of doing it with Flask?

The second view:

```
@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def metric_requirements():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    for m in request.form.getlist('form'):
        ...
        [store the data in a db with the username as the primary key]
        ...
  return render_template('add_form.html')
```

Comment: Why not set the user ID in the session?

Comment: Like @univerio said you can store ID (or username or something unique) in the session too (with the logged_in flag) or you can use https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ that handle all this stuff for you after configure it..

Comment: Also have a read of http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask